# Proof of $cax \equiv cd \ \ (\mathrm{mod} \ cm)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If we have the congruence equation
> $$cax \equiv cd \ \ (\mathrm{mod} \ cm),$$
> where $a,c,d,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $c = \mathrm{gcd}(ca,cm)$, then we can "divide" by $c$:
>
> $$ax \equiv d \ \ (\mathrm{mod} \ m),$$
>
> which has only one solution in modulo $m$, say $x_0$ (and assume $x_0$ is the smallest positive solution in modulo $m$). In modulo $cm$, we would have $c$ amount of solutions, namely:
> $$x\equiv x_0,x_0 + m,x_0 + 2m, \ldots, x_0 + (c-1)m.$$

This was a theorem given in the notes with no proof.

That is, we have $c$ solutions in the original modulus $cm$, and the solutions will differ by multiples of $m$.
I'm not sure how I can start or get a proof out for it.

Comment: Which theorem? The first step where you divide by $c$ or the second step where you add $m$?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it in to make it clearer

Comment: ax ≡ d mod(m) implies ax - d is divisible by m , thus ax*c - d*c is divisible by c and m

Comment: If $x=x_0$ is a solution of $cax \equiv cd \pmod {cm}$, then so is $x=x_0+m$, since $ca(x_0+m) = cax_0 + cm \equiv cax_0 \pmod{cm}$

Comment: Use `$\pmod{cm}$` for $\pmod{cm}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $cax=cd\pmod{cm}$, then by definition $$cm\mid cax-cd$$ so that $c(ax-d)=ecm$ for some $e\in \Bbb Z$. Divide by $c$.

Can you carry on from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at it this way, the congruence is equivalent to cax=cmy+cd= c(my+d) . dividing both sides by c, we get ax=my+d which is equivalent to the latter congruence.